# Does 'Allah' mean 'the-God' in Arabic?

Tags: allah

Can someone explain me if it means 'the-God' in Arabic? or is 'Allah' the name of the God? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

- **Allah** is a name and not a translation of God, and that is the name he called himself in Quran.
- There is disagreement whether it is allowed to translate the name **Allah** to God when conversing with people who do not speak Arabic, the rejection of  translating the name justifies that by:

  1. Names are not supposed to be translated, and translations usually cause a loss in the meaning.
  2. The translated words may invoke different  visualization in the recipient’s mind, for example when we say God in conversation with a Christian person he will think of the Trinity, which is completely different from what “Allah” indicates ( the one unique worshiped)
     therefor using the name as is “**Allah**” is considered better.

Comment: Could you please refer to some documents that prove that 'Allah' is the name by itself? thanks

Comment: Sure it is in almost in every verses of Quran: such as : "He is Allah , other than whom there is no deity, Knower of the unseen and the witnessed. He is the Entirely Merciful, the Especially Merciful.", it is in Hadith too:    'Aishah (May Allah be pleased with her) reported:
Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said, "When any of you wants to eat, he should mention the Name of Allah in the begining, (i.e., say Bismillah). If he forgets to do it in the beginning, he should say Bismillah awwalahu wa akhirahu (I begin with the Name of Allah at the beginning and at the end)."

Comment: This is a rather weak answer, given that your arguments also apply to the *other* 98 Names of God, which *are* indisputably just Arabic "the-[something]" constructions.

Comment: @goldPseudo ,Saying( weak argument) is unnecessary judging caused by your misunderstanding. -The question is about “Allah” and not about the other attributes (which by the way not limited to 98 or 99) hence your comment is mixing subjects. - There is a proper answer to your comment:
The difference between the name "Allah" and the remaining attributes, is that the name"Allah" is the name of the self, and is indicative of all the attributes and supreme qualities , it is indicative of the form which includes all  involved to prove the divine qualities and denying their opposites.

Comment: divine recipes are perfect recipes far above defects and shortcomings, Thus the Almighty adds other attributes to the name Allah, such as saying: ((And to Allah belong the best names)) {Araf180} and as in AlRahman, AlRahim Al-Aziz,and you read : AlRahman is attribute of Allah but you do not read Allah is attribute to  AlRahman.

Comment: @M.M Have you considered that Allah is in Arabic and also means The God in Arabic? Also consider the verse of surat Yusuf:
"Indeed, We have sent it down as an Arabic Qur'an that you might understand."

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, to me this is "The God". In Arabic ila means god, this means any god, god can be a stick, a rock, idol etc... But when you but the definite article "al" in frount of ila, the word become Allah "The God", referring to the one and only God of Adam, Moses, Abraham etc...